# SWT black background TreeViewer to set expand icon to bright gray

Tags: user-interface, windows-7, java-6, eclipse-3.6, treeviewer

```
org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.getControl().setForeground(COLOR_WHITE);
org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.getControl().setBackground(COLOR_BLACK);
```

When setting SWT TreeViewer background to black, the color theme of expand/collapse icon doesn't change accordingly. Its color is still black by default, which makes it's hard to observe in black background. How do I set the icon to gray like below screenshot?

[image]

Comment: On my Mac this just happens automatically.

Comment: It seems to be a Windows only issue.